# Attaching sources for eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I cannot inspect source code from eclipse plugin

**Eclipse plugin:**

[image]

What I do is this,

**Attaching plugin as source:**

[image]

What I do wrong, here is my eclipse info

**Eclipse info:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Eclipse SDK" includes source code plug-ins for all the Eclipse plug-ins. If you are using a target platform you should include this in the target platform. If you are just using the "Running Platform" as your target platform install it as part of your main Eclipse.

In the Preferences in the "Plug-in Development" page check the "Include all plug-ins from target in Java workspace scope" option. You should now be able to open any Eclipse class using the normal methods of viewing a type (such as "Open Type")

Comment: My "Running Platform" is the target platform.
And I include "all plug-ins from target in Java workspace scope".
A External Plug-in Libraries folder is shown in workspace, but I still see the class files.
I think maybe this part is missing "as your target platform install it as part of your main Eclipse". How can I do this?

Comment: Help > Install New Software. Choose the updates site for your release (`https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.21` for the current 2021-09 for example) and find Eclipse SDK

Comment: ok works fine, thx!